# Splitting up a text file into two files (java)

Tags: java, algorithm

I need some help into figuring out how to split a text file into two files in java.

I have a text file in which each line contains in alphabetical order a word a space and its index, i.e.

```
...

stand 345

stand 498

stare 894

...
```

What I would like to do is to read in this file and then write two separate files. One file should contain only one instance of the word and the other the positions of the word in the document. 
The file is really big and I was wondering if I can use an array or a list to store the word and index before creating the file or if there is a better way.
I don't really know how to think.

Comment: sort the file first, then read line by line until the word change => profit

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Do you want to store the indices attached with the words in a different file. 
In your example, should one file store
stand
stare 

and the other file should store 
345
498
894 

or is it something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is really long, then you should consider using a database. If your file is not too big then you can use a HashMap. You can also use a class like this, it requires that the file is sorted, and it writes the words in one file and the indices in another file:

```
public class Split {
private String fileName;
private PrintWriter fileWords;
private PrintWriter fileIndices;

public Split(String fname) {
    fileName = fname;
    if (initFiles()) {
        writeList();
    }
    closeFiles();
}

private boolean initFiles() {
    boolean retval = false;
    try {
        fileWords = new PrintWriter("words-" + fileName, "UTF-8");
        fileIndices = new PrintWriter("indices-" + fileName, "UTF-8");
        retval = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return retval;
}

private void closeFiles() {
    if (null != fileWords) {
        fileWords.close();
    }
    if (null != fileIndices) {
        fileIndices.close();
    }
}

private void writeList() {
    String lastWord = null;
    List<String> wordIndices = new ArrayList<String>();
    Path file = Paths.get(fileName);
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file, charset)) {
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            int len = line.length();
            if (len > 0) {
                int ind = line.indexOf(' ');
                if (ind > 0 && ind < (len - 1)) {
                    String word = line.substring(0, ind);
                    String indice = line.substring(ind + 1, len);
                    if (!word.equals(lastWord)) {
                        if (null != lastWord) {
                            writeToFiles(lastWord, wordIndices);
                        }
                        lastWord = word;
                        wordIndices = new ArrayList<String>();
                        wordIndices.add(indice);
                    } else {
                        wordIndices.add(indice);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (null != lastWord) {
            writeToFiles(lastWord, wordIndices);                    
        }
    } catch (IOException x) {
        System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
    }
}

private void writeToFiles(String word, List<String> list) {

    boolean first = true;
    fileWords.println(word);
    for (String elem : list) {
        if (first) {
            first = false;
        }
        else {
            fileIndices.print(" ");
        }
        fileIndices.print(elem);

    }
    fileIndices.println();
}
```

}

Be careful that the file name handling is not very robust, you can use it that way:

```
Split split = new Split("data.txt") ;
```

Comment: thank you so much. I am using your code as a reference and trying to recreate it!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to create a HashMap using the word as key and a list of indexes as value, like **HashMap< String, ArrayList< String >>**. This way you can easily check the words you already have put in the map, and update its index list.

```
List<String> list = map.get(word);
if (list == null)
{
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    map.put(word, list);
}
list.add(index);
```

After reading and storing all values, you just need to iterate through the map and write its keys in one file and values in another.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  String key = entry.getKey();
  ArrayList value = (ArrayList) entry.getValue();
  // writing code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to save the words and the indices. You just need to call `addLine` for each line of your file.

```
Map<String, Set<Integer>> entries = new LinkedHashMap<>();

public void addLine(String word, Integer index) {
    Set<Integer> indicesOfWord = entries.get(word);

    if (indicesOfWord == null) {
        entries.put(word, indicesOfWord = new TreeSet<>());
    }

    indicesOfWord.add(index);
}
```

To store them in separate files you can use this method:

```
public void storeInSeparateFiles(){
    for (Entry<String, Set<Integer>> entry : entries.entrySet()) {
        String word = entry.getKey();
        Set<Integer> indices = entry.getValue();

        // TODO: Save in separate files.
    }
}
```